# Best seo pratice for category pages

Tags: seo, ecommerce, technical-seo, categories, products

Let's say you have an e-commerce store that has a category page of "Easter Offers" with an URL of /easter-offers which contains special discounted products which only easter for Easter.

Within this store, you also have a generic "Offers" category with a URL of /offers which contains special discounted products and is available all year around.

After Easter, the /easter-offers will have 0 products displayed but you want to use this URL year after year.

What would be the best SEO practice in maintaining the /easter-offers page?

1. After easter implement a 307 temporary redirect to /offers and remove it again before the next easter
2. Keep /easter-offers active with no products but add content to the page informing easter offers are now finished and they should come back next year
3. Something else - If this option please explain

Answer (score 1):

I think option 2 -- keep the /easter-offers page active -- is for sure your best approach.

After the sale is over, you'll have to remove the products from that page, but since it's a category page, you can add all kinds of content about what last year's easter offers were (just no way to add them to the cart after the sale is over) and what will be coming next year.

Right after the sale ends, I would change the page content and metadata to Easter Offers 2024, and then make sure to update the content as often as possible, basically making it a "Future Easter Offers" page until you get closer to the next Easter Offers sale.

Hope that helps. I'm interested to see what others might suggest. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use redirects, that's for sure. Pages need to be up and running 24/7 in order to build up age and behavioral factors.

What I noticed from practice is that 10 products in a category is already an indicator of a normal page. So, you just need to leave 10 products in the category after the sale. Accordingly,
in order not to mislead people, it needs to be "marked" in some way. For example, you can specify that these products are being prepared for the Easter sale of the year N.

You need to turn on the fantasy and just submit it correctly.